# c# simulate mouse wheel down

Tags: c#, .net

I use the following code:

```
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;

public void MouseWheelUp()
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, 120, 0);
}
```

But how do I make it work for scrolling down?

Comment: Could you add the code or import for 'mouse_event'

Comment: Mouse Event Import: `[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);`

Comment: Please note that a uint cannot be assigned a negative value. Therefore take caution using Michal's method signature.

Comment: For example: public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, IntPtr dwExtraInfo); may work better for you. Example usage: mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0,  -120, (IntPtr) 0);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**`mouse_event function`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx)

function signature:

```
VOID WINAPI mouse_event(
  _In_ DWORD     dwFlags,
  _In_ DWORD     dx,
  _In_ DWORD     dy,
  _In_ DWORD     dwData,
  _In_ ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo
);
```

> If `dwFlags` contains `MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL`, then `dwData` specifies the amount of wheel movement. A positive value indicates that the wheel was rotated forward, away from the user; a negative value indicates that the wheel was rotated backward, toward the user. One wheel click is defined as `WHEEL_DELTA`, which is 120.

To scroll down :

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -120, 0);
```

Comment: This have been superseded, use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.